# How do I find output for this in sqlite? NULL

Tags: sqlite, join, group-by, having

I have been trying to write a query using INNER JOIN and CASE WHEN with SUM to find the movieName where all personnel that are cast in the movie are not dead (all NULL then I need movieName linked to uniqueMovieID)?

I have 3 tables:
Table 1: movies
Schema: uniqueMovieId, movieName
Table 2: cast
Schema: uniqueMovieId, castId
Table 3: personnel
Schema: castId, yearOfDeath

If a personnel has not died there is NULL in yearOfDeath.

Output:
MovieName_1 <- all cast are alive
MovieName_2 <- all cast are alive
....
MovieName_n <- all cast are alive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables and group by movie.
Apply the condition in the `HAVING` clause with an aggregate function like `MAX()` or `MIN()` or `SUM()`:

```
SELECT m.uniqueMovieId, 
       m.MovieName
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN cast c ON c.uniqueMovieId = m.uniqueMovieId
INNER JOIN personnel p ON p.castId = c.castId
GROUP BY m.uniqueMovieId
HAVING MAX(p.yearOfDeath) IS NULL;
```